# Marginal Cost and Avg cost optimization problem

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I have this problem:

> If $C(x) = 16,000 + 200x + 4x^{3/2}$, in dollars, find
>
> 1. the cost, average cost, and marginal cost at a production level of $1000$ units;
> 2. the production level that will minimize the average cost; and
> 3. the minimum average cost.

So for (i):

$$
C(x) = 16000 + 200x + 4x^{3/2}
\implies
C(1000) = 342491.11$$

So

Avg cost = $342491.11/1000 = 342.49$

Marg Cost function is given by 
$$
M(x) = C'(x) = 200 + 6x^{1/2}
\implies
M(1000) = 390.74
$$

(ii)
$$
\begin{split}
A(x)  &= \frac{16000 + 200x + 4x^{3/2}}{x}\\
A'(x) &= \frac{x \cdot (200 + 6x^{1/2} - (16000 - 200x + 4x^{3/2}}{x^2}\\
      &= \frac{200 + 6x^{\frac{3}{2}} - (16000 - 200x - 4x^{3/2}}{x^2}\\
      &= \frac{2x^{3/2} - 16000}{x^2} \\
      &= 0
\end{split}
$$

when $2x^{\frac{3}{2}} = 16000 \implies x^{3/2} = 8000$

So after taking the cube root of 8000 and squaring it, $x = 400$

Did I make any mistakes?

(iii) 320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all are correct but (ii) may seem more direct if you divide the fraction to get
$$
A(x) = 16000 x^{-1} + 200 + 4x^{1/2}
$$
so
$$
A'(x) = 2x^{-1/2} - 16000x^{-2}
$$
thus $A'(x) = 0$ yields $8000 = x^{3/2}$ so $x = 400$.

Answer (score 0):

your first derivative can simplified to $$A'(x)=2\,{\frac { \left( \sqrt {x}-20 \right)  \left( x+20\,\sqrt {x}+400
 \right) }{{x}^{2}}}
$$
and $$A'(x)=0$$ if $x=400$ as you stated.